# Forgot password to Etherbase wallet (version 3)?

Tags: password, myetherwallet

I created an Ethereum wallet through the Ethereum application. I subsequently forgot my password and am now trying to recover it using Pyethrecover. The problem is, the keystore wallet file created within the application (version 3) does not explicitly provide the encrypted seed; something that is required for pyethrecover to work. Is there a way to convert to wallet version 1 without a password? Or is there some other way that I can run Pyethrecover without the encrypted seed?

Answer (score 1):

(Note this is a duplicate of my answers to [How to apply pyethrecover.py on v3 .json/transfor v3 .json to .v1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6845/2887) . Reposting here since I don't have enough rep to comment)

I had the same problem. I had created a wallet using `geth` and somehow I wrote down the wrong password. I used the simple `python` code below to solve the issue. I know it's not pretty, but I just needed a quick solution to my problem. Someone else might pick this up and make a proper tool, or perhaps I get around to it one day as a good `python` learning experience. I tested some 100k password and I was able to recover using this code. It follows a similar format as `pyethrecover` (the presale tool) and uses `pyethereum` to decode the keystore file.

You need to download/install the `pyethereum` library: https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum 
See documentation there for requirements and how to.

From `pyethereum` we need `keys.py` which has the function `decode_keystore_json`

```
from keys import decode_keystore_json #keys.py from pyethereum, we only want the decode_keystore_json function
import json
import itertools
import sys

f = open('wallet.json') # the json account file from keystore, here renamed
jsondata=json.load(f)
```

Run the following if you have a text file with the different passwords you want to try written down, one on each line:

```
# Reading possible passwords from a text file
with open('listofpasswords.txt') as fpw: # a text file with possible passwords on each line
    lines = fpw.read().splitlines()

n_pws = len(lines)
print 'Number of passwords to test: %d' % (n_pws,)
i=1
for l in lines:
    try:
        decode_keystore_json(jsondata,l)
        print '\n*** found password in text file:'
        print l
        break
    except:
        sys.stdout.write("\r#%d %s" % (i,l)) #prints simple progress with # in list that is tested and the pw string
        sys.stdout.flush()
        i+=1
```

Or this code if you want to construct passwords from possible combinations (see pyethrecover example 2):

```
# Constructing passwords from possible combinations (see doc of pyethrecover)
grammar=[
    ('correct',),
    ('horse','donkey'),
    ('staple','STAPLE'),
    ('','battery')
]

pwds=[]
def generate_all(el, tr): #taken from pyethrecover
    if el:
        for j in xrange(len(el[0])):
            for w in generate_all(el[1:], tr + el[0][j]):
                yield w
    else:
        yield tr


pwds = itertools.chain(pwds, generate_all(grammar,''))
pwds_l = list(pwds)
n_pws = len(pwds_l)
print 'Number of passwords to test: %d' % (n_pws,)
i=1
for l in pwds_l:
    try:
        decode_keystore_json(jsondata,l)
        print '\n*** found password in grammar list:'
        print l
        break
    except:
        sys.stdout.write("\r#%d %s" % (i,l)) #prints simple progress with # in list that is tested and the pw string
        sys.stdout.flush()
        i+=1
```

Good luck!