# pyethrecover v3 need help

Tags: pyethereum

I have lost my mist wallet password (1 year ago)

i tried pyethrecover but... no error , no luck... i guess because i have mist .089 keysotre file... so i tried this one:

[How to apply pyethrecover.py on v3 .json/transfor v3 .json to .v1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6845/how-to-apply-pyethrecover-py-on-v3-json-transfor-v3-json-to-v1)

and i use pyethrecoverv3

i create new wallet with very simple password

password is: qwe

and i try to use this

> w = {
>     "address": "a0d8b24364e6a0782741091e9a8afe51a3225758",
>     "crypto": {
>       "cipher": "aes-128-ctr",
>       "ciphertext": "12972a53599542829e01f3a8170f4d40fa2b31505eed5851db631a064f50fea4",
>       "cipherparams": {
>         "iv": "5df8949e399b6aae58381a6f8b791c25"
>       },
>       "kdf": "scrypt",
>       "kdfparams": {
>         "dklen": 32,
>         "n": 262144,
>         "p": 1,
>         "r": 8,
>         "salt": "6e5ef6f1c6644fdd6bd18dd9cdcbafa26ca57a0da084e640a0b30791bdb66a9b"
>       },
>       "mac": "064b2575bc5a0a71295540870d88371a85af5bd237aac154e9dbaced50b756eb"
>     },
>     "id": "1dab3409-aec4-4591-b054-6e5971c746f4",
>     "version": 3
>   }

and i try to use this password "qwe" and i see "attempts" ... i see attempt with correct password but ... there is no luck showing it...

any help?