# Crypto package not resolving

Tags: blockchain, pyethereum, encryption

I have the same problem as in 'How to apply pyethrecover.py on v3 .json/transfor v3 .json to .v1' referenced [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6845/how-to-apply-pyethrecover-py-on-v3-json-transfor-v3-json-to-v1/17149#17149), but in trying the answer's code, I am finding that the Crypto package is not being recognized.

I installed 'Crypto' from within PyCharm and it reports installing (i.e. notification and event logs), but the IDE still shows this it as an 'Unresolved Reference' and produces the error below while running utils.py:

```
try:
    from Crypto.Hash import keccak
    sha3_256 = lambda x: keccak.new(digest_bits=256, data=x).digest()
except ImportError:
    import sha3 as _sha3
    sha3_256 = lambda x: _sha3.keccak_256(x).digest()
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'keccak_256'

What am I missing? I am using Python 2.7.10 in PyCharm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is more than likely a PyCharm issue, rather than anything related to Ethereum Python code.

You'll need to ensure the `Unresolved reference` error is resolved before the `Crypto` package can be used. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm) StackOverflow question for steps to overcome this.

(The actual runtime error you're hitting is because you're entering the `except` path, and `sha3` is either not present, or also not resolving.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I'll work that way and report back what I find.