# is it possible to have a password bug in mist wallet 0.8.10

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ether

I was playing with account creation with in MIST and i find one account always saying "password wrong" when i try to transfer ether to other accounts. It can still receive ether though.

I use same password for all accounts in MIST, so I am 99.9% sure password is the regular password i use.

Comment: If there is such a bug that would have been notified by now. Its a big community my friend. On the other hand, its too silly to have a password bug in any application. :D

Comment: Make sure you have download from the offical page https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases, if you think that it might be a regression you can try with a previous version. OTOH You should *not* reuse passwords it is bad security practice.

Comment: I guess i have to spend a day on password cracking. @Ismael I agree on password reuse but then i can't even get that right :)

Comment: I have used [pyethrecover](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6845/how-to-apply-pyethrecover-py-on-v3-json-transfor-v3-json-to-v1/12249#12249) to recover my password. Apparently i have added an extra random character at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened to me. Happened when I upgraded to 0.8.10 and changed computers to a new one and imported the key. I am 100% certain it was the correct password because I had it written down. Not to mention I've sent ether from it on several occasions, and recently too. Lost everything. Goodluck - doesn't seem like anyone can and/or will help.

Comment: Hi there. Please see the final comment under the question - the user resolved their issue :-)

Comment: If you wrote your password down, could you have possibly made a transcription error?

Comment: Another idea: if your password contains special characters, sometimes those characters are different between different keyboard layouts. If your machine has for some reason switched layouts (mine used to do it all the time... UK->US layout), you might not be typing in what you think you're typing.

Comment: Please Fort9520  leave this information as an comment since this is not an answer to the question (in the future).